# Looking for a wheel

Tags: sensors, wheel

If this is not the right community please point me in the right direction.

I am looking for a speed measuring wheel similar to the one in the picture..

What is it called?

I have googled for a description and used an image search for google but can't find a wheel that's the same.

It is for a Square Meter measuring table in our factory. Everywhere we ask they want to supply us with an encoder that is directly connected to the wheel. This means the encoder is spinning the whole time. We don't want this setup.
What were looking for is a wheel that can be used by the pickup sensor that is connected to the bracket, and the wheel must have its own bearing.
I have added descriptions on the image.
[image: Pickup Sensor with Wheel]

Comment: `This means the encoder is spinning the whole time.` ... if the wheel is not turning, then the encoder is not turning

Comment: The problem is that we had a running encoder setup before the current one and the encoder shafts don't last at all. Thats when we changed over to the pickup sensor. Now we cant find a new wheel . The wheel is what I am looking for. We can not find a proper description.

Comment: The whole assembly is referred to as a conveyor wheel encoder, or conveyor measuring wheel, or possibly measuring wheel encoder. I think what you are looking for is the "wheel" part of the apparatus. Baumer makes them, but I doubt they make them in your flavor. You may be able to modify a conveyor skate wheel by putting in the metal inserts yourself if you can't find a direct replacement. The key part here is that you know how many pulses per unit length you're getting from the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device you're looking for is called a [Hall-effect sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_sensor). There's a decent video on how they work [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpAA3qeOYiI), and they're commonly used as crankshaft and camshaft position sensors in vehicles.

A typical Hall-effect sensor will only send a pulse when the magnetic/ferrous object passes by the sensor, so you've got no way to determine direction. If you want to determine direction, too, then you should look for a Hall-effect [quadrature encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoder#Quadrature_outputs).

Comment: We implemented a Hall sensor one time that used a single sensor, and two discrete magnets, relatively close together, of opposite polarity, in order to determine direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Direction is not a problem.